# Solving system of linear equations over a finite field python or java

Tags: java, python, algebra, linear-equation, finite-field

Is there any package in python or java that can solve a system of linear equations over a finite field? I'm trying to solve 20+ equations with 20+ unknown variables and having this package would be great. This is a system of equations over a finite field so it's not quite the same as solving regular linear equations.

Additions, subtraction, multiplication, and division follow the set of rules [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Addition_and_subtraction) for finite fields. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).

It's very powerful mathematics system written in Python. It's syntax is nearly identical as Python's.

Finite field operations are in [this](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/rings_standard/sage/rings/finite_rings/constructor.html) package.